# Why the address of main function's parameter change each time?

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point, memory-address

I write a test which print the content of argv[0]--the address of main function's parameter as followed:

```
printf("%p\n",argv[0]);
```

I compiled the program with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.

Then I executed the program 1000 times which output the results to a file. As a result, the address of argv[0] changes, however, some addresses are the same and repeat about 10 times.

Why the address of main function's parameter changes each time?

Comment: Why should it be the same every time?  Why do you care in the slightest?  An acronym for you: ASLR - Address Space Layout Randomization.

Comment: +1 for ASLR. A coolest of all technologies to make a bad application even worse. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: To print a pointer portably, you need to cast to `void*`: `printf("%p\n", (void*)argv);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, I see very few or no reasons for non-determinism of that in program's own address space. But I will tell you what I do know.

First, argv is allocated, created and initialized not by windows but by stdc runtime. Which, in turn, raises another question - does lpCmdLine parameter of winmain also change? There're several other variables allocated on the same heap, probably environment vars are also copied. One of them must have size depending on the instance of execution.

Anyway, why blackbox pondering? Where's your disassembler, soldier?

Answer (score 2):

`argc` and `argv` should be placed onto the stack before the begin of the main routine of the binary executable. Actually I think that `argv` is dynamically allocated somewhere inside the heap and then the pointer is placed onto the stack.

This means that the heap allocator is the one that cares about where the data is allocated and this is why it changes everytime (it depends on the policy).. your program will ask to the OS to allocate the space for the arguments (think about passing through `malloc`) so there can be internal choices made according to something (like the ASLR they were talking about)

Comment: OS is has no part in this. Program's address space should not depend on availability of physical ram pages

Comment: I'm not talking about paging. I'm talking about the fact that the virtual address is chosen ANYWAY by the OS memory allocator. Of course the physical address is invisible and unknown to the program, but the virtual one is too when you pass through a syscall like `malloc`.

Comment: But malloc is not part of the OS, nor does OS have a say about virtual address these params will get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here's what the language standard ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) has to say:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
> constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
>
>   `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
>   If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>   shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
>
>   If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the *program name*; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the *program parameters*.
>
>   The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

The last bullet is the most interesting with respect to *where* the string arguments passed to `main` are stored.  They must be modifiable and they must have static extent, which places some limits on where they reside in memory.  There's no requirement on the part of the language definition that they reside in the same location every time the program is run, though.

I've done a cursory search through MSDN to see if they say anything explicit, but haven't found anything yet.  It probably comes down to ASLR as mentioned in the comments to the OP.

Comment: Surely no requirement, also no requirement they should differ. Nothing to do with the fact bring surprising.